# Zend Form Element Captcha - reCAPTCHA - Conditionally Required

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, captcha, recaptcha, zend-form-element

I have a Zend Form Captcha Element using reCAPTCHA, and it works perfectly. I want to make the field conditionally required, but it seems to always be required, ignoring the `required` setting on the element. I understand that it sounds silly to have the element but not have it required, but that's exactly what I need to accomplish.

Comment: Can you conditionally add it to the form instead?

Comment: @TimFountain - I can't, because it needs to be in the form and shown/hidden based on a radio button selection.

Comment: In your controller code, if the radio is checked, remove the captcha element from the form object? Or vice-versa.

Comment: @Ashley - When re-displaying the form, if there's a submission error, I wouldn't be able to do a JavaScript show/hide.

Comment: If there's an error, create a new instance of the form, and use `->populate`?

Comment: @Ashley - Each form element has decorators that display the error messages. Your suggestion would lose that. What I really need is what I asked for in the OP.